# How can I specify "don't care" signals in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, optimization

In Logic Design courses we all learned that it is possible to minimize a logic function, for example by using a Karnaugh map or the [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm). We also learned that ["Don't Care"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't-care_%28logic%29) values increase the minimization potential.

For example take a register file. The `write_address` and `write_data` signals don't really matter when the `write_enable` signal is `'0'`. Thus, they should be assigned a "Don't Care" value to allow more optimizations in the logic that is *driving* these signals (i.e. not in the register file itself).

**What is the correct way to specify such "Don't Care" values in VHDL in order to allow the synthesis tool more room for possible optimizations?**

---

So far I've found the following things which might be suitable. But I'm not really sure what the pros and cons of each approach are:

- Simply not assigning the signal. This seems like it could work. However I found that it doesn't work when you want to define a "do nothing constant" of some `record` type, since record constants need to be fully specified (at least Modelsim tells me so).
- The `std_logic_1164` package defines the value `'-'   -- Don't care` for `std_ulogic`. This looks like it is the semantically correct choice for an explicit "don't care", but I've never seen it used anywhere (except in the unrelated VHDL-2008 `case?` constructs).
- Modelsim uses the value `'X'` to display undefined signals. However I'm not sure if synthesis tools understand an explicit `'X'`-assignment as "don't care".

Here's an oversimplified code snippet for clarification, where I've initialized the don't care signals with `'-'`.

As you can see, the signal `control.reg_write_address` can have 3 different values: `"----"`, `instruction(11 downto 8);` and `instruction(3 downto 0);`. Now I'd expect this to be synthesized to a 2-input multiplexer if `'-'` is interpreted as "don't care". Had I initialized the signal with `(others => '0')` instead of `'-'`, the tool would have to generate a 3-input multiplexer instead.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package mytypes is
    type control_signals_t is record
        write_enable  : std_logic;
        write_address : std_ulogic_vector(3 downto 0);
        read_address  : std_ulogic_vector(3 downto 0);
    end record;

    -- All members of this constant must be fully specified.
    -- So it's not possible to simply not assign a value.
    constant CONTROL_NOP : control_signals_t := (
        write_enable  => '0',
        write_address => (others => '-'),
        read_address  => (others => '-')
    );
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
library cfx;
use cfx.mytypes.all;

entity control_unit is
    port(
        instruction : in  std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);
        write_data  : out std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);
        ctrl        : out control_signals_t
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of control_unit is
begin
    decode_instruction : process(instruction) is
    begin
        -- Set sensible default values that do nothing.
        -- Especially all "write_enable" signals should be '0'.
        -- Everything else is mostly irrelevant (don't care).
        ctrl       <= CONTROL_NOP;
        write_data <= (others => '-');

        if instruction(15 downto 12) = "1100" then
            -- Load 8 bit of data into the register file
            ctrl.write_enable  <= '1';
            write_data         <= std_ulogic_vector(resize(signed(instruction(7 downto 0)), 16));
            ctrl.write_address <= instruction(11 downto 8);
        elsif instruction(15 downto 8) = "11111001" then
            -- Load 4 bit of data into the register file
            write_data         <= std_ulogic_vector(resize(signed(instruction(7 downto 4)), 16));
            ctrl.write_address <= instruction(3 downto 0);
        elsif instruction(15 downto 8) = "10110101" then
            -- Read from the register file. Don't use the write signals at all.
            ctrl.read_address <= instruction(3 downto 0);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do with `write_address` and `write_data`? What optimization do you expect to take place?

Comment: I hope the example makes it more clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will leave it to an LRM expert to provide a more detailed answer, but in short, your approach should be valid - I ran a quick test with a recent version of Quartus, and it handles `'-'` like it's supposed to - the logic generated is reduced as expected when the output is defaulted to `'-'` (`'X'` works too, by the way). More on the approaches you listed:

- Not assigning the signal isn't really an option for your example, of course, if you don't want latches. If it's a clocked process, you're slightly better off, but you'll still get enables where you might not need them. Maybe I'm missing your intent here.
- `'-'`, as previously noted, is probably the best option, for both semantic and practical reasons.
- Depends on what you mean by "undefined". `'X'` is technically "unknown". `'U'` is for uninitialized signals, which ModelSim displays as `"X"` for hex representations. `'X'` does seem to work, though, as I noted above.

Another alternative would be to do the optimization yourself and remove one case from being tested explicitly:

```
if instruction(15 downto 8) = "11111001" then
  write_data <= std_ulogic_vector(resize(signed(instruction(7 downto 4)), 16));
else
  write_data <= std_ulogic_vector(resize(signed(instruction(7 downto 0)), 16));
end if;
```

This has significant disadvantages (mostly related to code clarity), though, and I would probably opt for a more ideal solution.

Incidentally, `'-'` is also commonly used with `std_match()`, which I would consider using for your decoding, e.g.:

```
if std_match(instruction(15 downto 8), "1100----") then
```

Though at that point, you're probably better off just using `case?`.

Answer (score 7):

In short: It's legal VHDL and it's typically supported by synthesis tools.

It is however rather uncommon to see it used. I don't really know why. Your code seems to me to be a good example of when it would be meaningful to use it.

There is however *one drawback* that one should be aware of: at synthesis, the functions driving outputs where don't care's are involved could be *different* between synthesis runs. This makes the synthesis less deterministic. If outputs that have been defined as don't care are used (by mistake), this can make the error harder to find.

**Tool support**

At least the following tools will accept don't cares and make use of the optimization possibilities:

- Xilinx (ref.: "XST User Guide")
- Altera (ref.: "Recommended HDL Coding Styles")
- Synplify (ref.: "Synplify reference manual")

Xilinx and Altera will treat `'-'` and `'X'` as don't care, Synplify will treat those and furthermore `'U'` and `'W'` (weak) as don't care.

Comment: I had another application of that drawback. The code worked in simulation, but not on the FPGA, because my code looked like: `if signal = '1' then a; else b; end if;`. Unfortunately the `signal` wasn't `1` or `0` but `-`. So in the simulation, the `else` branch was executed, but in hardware the `-` turned out to be a `1`, so the true branch was executed...

Comment: Yeah, I've had similar bugs pass simulation, but most often in my case there are the `'U'`s, common in the beginning of simulations, that have been used leading to some `else` code block being executed. It would be wonderful if conditionals could somehow be made to propagate `'U'`s, similar to the behaviour of concurrent boolean expressions.

Comment: After I found that bug I made sure to *always* write something like `if signal = '1' then output <= '1'; elsif signal='0' then output <= '0'; else output <= '-'; end if;`. And I added the following to all registers and memories: `assert not is_X(write_enable) report "we=" & str(A_write_enable) severity ERROR;` and `if write_enable = '1' then assert not is_X(write_addr) report "write_addr=str(write_addr) severity ERROR; end if;`. Plus the same for `write_data`. Together, that should catch almost all of these errors.

Comment: That's a way, but that's way too verbose for me. I would wish for this possibility within the VHDL language.

Comment: In your case, I would prefer driving to `'X'` ("unknown") rather than `'-'`, or, even better, propagating `'-'` on input to `'-'` on output and everything else that is not `0` or `1` to `'X'` - that's a bit more logical.

Checking for `'X'` etc. on `write enable`'s is a good idea and I often do it. (The check on addr/data when `write enable='1'` is a further step of course.)

Comment: Well yes, VHDL is a bit verbose, but that's just the VHDL way. :D On the other hand it is also very explicit, and doesn't do "black magic" behind my back, which I find quite nice (cf. The Zen of Python "Explicit is better than implicit").